# Grid is left-aligned. How to always display the second column if the first col. is too wide?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

What do I have:

```
<Grid HorizontalAligment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <TextBlock Text="Text" Grid.Column="0" />
  <Grid Background="Black" VerticalAligment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1">
    <TextBlock Text="*" />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Result:

```
__________
|        |
|Text *  |
|________|
```

I have a problem: when text is too wide, `*` becomes off screen.

```
__________
|        |
|long Tex|t *
|________|
```

So, how to specify that `*` should overlay part of the `Text` if it becomes off screen?

```
__________
|        |
|long Te*|t
|________|
```

The second problem: I cannot use MaxWidth for the `Text`, because `Grid` has a dynamic width.

**UPD**: If I would use `Width="*"` for the first column, I will get this:

```
__________
|        |
|Text   *|
|________|
```

Comment: No way setting the first column to * fixes this.   You set the second column width to 16 and it surprises you a width wider then 16 is truncated?

Comment: @Blam, nothing suprises me. I want to make the second column near the first column, and when the first column is too wide, to be not off screen. The textblock in the first column has a text binding, the second never changes.

Comment: you'd need 2 tables, put them in one container that allows overlaying and set the 2nd's Z axis to be in front of the first table and set 2nd table's position to be fixed. that way, whatever the size of the first table, it won't move the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
```

Instead of

```
<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
```

Edit:
Here is the full code:

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="123 Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really 
                   Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really 
                   Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really Text Long. Really 
                   " Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="*" />
            </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

The output is the following. 123 is start of the text. Is this not what you're expecting?

[image: The Output]

Comment: I want to make the second column near the content of the first (updated the question).

Comment: wouldn't the "*" will be at the right side, if text is too short (e.g. just "123")?